# How to shift hue of a color to opposite direction

Tags: opengl, glsl

i am not very proficient with shaders this is my attempt to write a shader which picks certain color and shfits the hue in opposite direction.

```
// convert to  YCC color model color 
vec2 RGBToCC(vec4 rgba) {
    float Y = 0.299 * rgba.r + 0.587 * rgba.g + 0.114 * rgba.b;
    return vec2((rgba.b - Y) * 0.565, (rgba.r - Y) * 0.713);
}       

vec2 RGBAToCC (float r, float g, float b) {
    
    float y = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b;    
    return vec2((b - y) * 0.565, (r - y) * 0.713);
}


void main() {
        texture2D( tex , uvCoord );
        vec4 src1Color = texture2D(u_tex,  texCoord);
            keyCC = RGBAToCC( colorToPick.r , colorToPick.g , colorToPick.b  );
            vec2 CC = RGBToCC(src1Color);
            float myCol = sqrt(pow(keyCC.x - CC.x, 2.0) + pow(keyCC.y - CC.y, 2.0));
            myCol = smoothstep(range.x, range.y, mask);
         if (myCol == 0.0) 
        {
                         // i want to shift the hue of the color to opposite direction
                        // if it is green than shift it toward magenta


        }
}
```

I am able to pick the color but i am not able to understand how to shift the hue of the color to opposite direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the YCbCr color space the two C… components are color balance values with values in the range [-1,1]. Hue inversion is as simple as flipping the sign of the color component vector, i.e. with the variables in your code `CC = -CC;`